# Bewilligung, Erlaubnis, Zustimmung und Genehmigung - der Unterschied

Tags: word-choice, synonym

Der Duden sagt:

> **die Genehmigung**
>       a. das Genehmigen 
>       b. Schriftstück, Papier, auf dem etwas (amtlich) genehmigt wird
>
> **die Erlaubnis**: 
>   Genehmigung, Zustimmung; Bestätigung, dass jemand etwas tun darf
>
> **die Bewilligung**: 
>       1. das Bewilligen 
>       2. (schriftliche) Zusage, dass etwas bewilligt wird
>
> **die Zustimmung**: 
>  das Zustimmen; Bejahung, Einverständnis

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen Wörtern?

Comment: Ich würde mal sagen, dass der Unterschied wesentlich vom **Kontext** abhängt, der ja in den ebenfalls von Duden genannten Anwendungsbeispielen schön gezeigt wird. Hast du damit Probleme? Man müsste evtl. die Frage noch ein wenig eingrenzen/präzisieren und in einen bestimmten Kontext setzen. Siehe auch http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences

Comment: Dass du jetzt noch nach der *Einwilligung* fragst, macht dich schon zu einem ziemlich beweglichen Ziel. Dadurch machst du quasi alle schon gegebenen Antworten unvollständig und »erwartest« neue. Ich weiß nicht, ob das gut ist … Bedenke, dass deine Frage drei Tage alt ist.

Comment: @Jan: Wäre ein Kommentar unter dem Fragepost besser?

Comment: Meines Erachtens schon, aber weil ich es nicht sicher weiß, [habe ich mal auf Meta eine Diskussion aufgemacht](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/903/late-extensions-to-questions-asking-about-differences-between-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eine **Genehmigung** ist eine behördliche **Erlaubnis**. Wenn ein Kind bei Freunden übernachten will bekommt es von der Mutter die **Erlaubnis**. Wenn die Mutter auf ihrem Grundstück ein Haus bauen will bekommt sie von der Behörde eine **Genehmigung**.

Eine **Bewilligung** ist die Zusage einer Leistung. Wer BAFöG beantragt, bekommt diese Leistung bewilligt.

**Zustimmung** zu bekommen ist nicht notwendigerweise ein autoritativer Vorgang – wenn Peter bei einem Freund übernachten will kann seine Schwester dem **zustimmen** – die **Erlaubnis** müssen aber die Eltern erteilen.

Comment: Und unterscheidet sich von den oben genannten Wörtern das Wort **Einwilligung**?

Comment: @marmistrz: "Einwilligung" würde ich verwenden, wenn mehrere Parteien zustimmen müssen oder sollen, und eine davon dies tut.

Answer (score 2):

Genehmigung und Bewilligung sind immer (?, oder wenigstens überwiegend) Akte von Behörden, Vorgesetzten oder anderen Autoritäten.

Erlaubnisse kann hingegen jeder Eigentümer bezüglich seines Eigentums erteilen. Auch können Eltern und sonstige Erziehungsberechtigte ihren Kindern Dinge erlauben oder verbieten.

Zustimmung hingegen ist etwas, das originär nur zwischen freien Menschen vorkommt, die einander als Gleiche gegenübertreten.

Kurz gesagt, der Freie sucht Zustimmung, der Knecht Genehmigungen und Bewilligungen.

Answer (score 1):

Eine **Zustimmung** *gibt* man, der Rest wird regelmäßig *erteilt*. Hierbei klingt gerade das erste Wort ein wenig offizieller. Bewilligt oder genehmigt werden kann beispielsweise ein behördlicher Antrag auf etwas. Die Erteilung einer Erlaubnis oder das „Geben“ einer Zustimmung ist von weniger offiziellem Charakter.

Comment: Es spricht überhaupt nichts dagegen auch eine Zustimmung zu _erteilen_. Gerade in juristischem Kontext (ich weiß, wovon ich rede) ist das sogar der Regelfall.